# Are those apartments in The Wire abandoned?

Tags: the-wire

In the tv show, The Wire, people live in apartments with barricaded doors and broken windows. One example is shown below:

[image]

Are those apartments abandoned or simply out of maintenance due to any reason?

Comment: Wallace and the kids he looks after are likely living in one, since the house is very bare and seems to using a wire to siphon electricity illegally from the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These buildings are frequently referred to as 'derelicts', especially in Season 4 when Chris and Snoop find a use for them.

You might live in one if you had no other choice but you'd have to break in if you didn't own it as the previous owners would have boarded it up. It wouldn't be especially habitable as they are generally falling down and disconnected from utilities.

Sadly a fact of life in American cities with high levels of bankruptcy and poverty such as Baltimore (most recent news stories estimate over 15,000 for that city).

Answer (score 3):

That location appears to be Hamsterdam from season 3. Apparently they are vacant houses. This link says they have since been torn down but when I do google street view I still see them there (still in rough shape/abandoned by the look at some of those buildings). My googling hasn't shown much but maybe this can help you or somebody find more information on them.

https://popturf.com/locations/television/the-wire/hamsterdam